# Why is my button function only providing output once?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am experimenting with a basic VSCode extension webview. I am trying to get a simple button click to display a message whenever it is clicked, but the message is only appearing the first time. My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Module Manager</title>
  <style> h1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:rgb(60,99,201);">
  <h1 style="color:white;">Welcome to the Lab Ticketing System</h1>
  
  <button onclick="moduleAdd()">Click me</button>
  
  <script>
    function moduleAdd(){
      const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi(); 
      vscode.postMessage({command: "alert", text: "BUTTON PRESSED!"});
    }
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Then, the javascript code:

```
let newCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('ticketing.start', function () {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Activating ticketing system!")
    
    // create webview
    const modulePanel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('modManage', "Module Manager",
    vscode.ViewColumn.One, {enableScripts: true}, );
    
    // pull in the HTML content for the webview panel from external module
    modulePanel.webview.html = htmlStuff.getWelcomeScreen();
    
    // handle recieving messages from the webview
    modulePanel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(message => 
        {switch(message.command){case 'alert': vscode.window.showErrorMessage(message.text);
        return;}}, undefined, context.subscriptions); 
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable, newCommand);
```

I'm leaving out some code that manages the extension, since the webview displays correctly I think it's just an issue with how I'm implementing the button.

Comment: only `acquireVsCodeApi()` once, outside the functions that need it

Comment: when you use a `style` tag, why hard code styles in the html tags

Comment: @rioV8 thank you! It was as easy as moving ```acquireVsCodeApi()``` outside the function as you said. And you're right, no reason, it's messy and I'll clean it up. I'm very new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only call `acquireVsCodeApi()` once, outside the functions that need it.